# How to connect to remote Elasticsearch from Kibana Docker image

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an ElasticSearch cluster running somewhere and I though to spin a Kibana container on my local machine and connect to the cluster, but it's not working. It looks like it's looking for a local ES.

> kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-08-31T09:06:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
> kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-08-31T09:06:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}

This is docker-compose.yml I'm using

```
version: "3"
services:
  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.0.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=https://esinstance.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=admin
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=pass123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need edit ENV `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` to `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`.
File `docker-compose.yml` will look like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.0.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["https://esinstance.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=admin
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=pass123
```

Comment: thanks. your solution worked, i only needed to remove the single quotes, so ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["https://esinstance.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]